In need to neglect play console tablets screenshots
The problem: I am publishing a flutter application on play console for my internal testing phase, and wondering if I could make some configurations so that I may abandon tablet screenshots to the project's store listing.
What I have: I manipulated my app's manifest.xml and added scripts that are supposed to exclusively support certain screen sizes.
What went wrong: This had major drawbacks, including the removal of my own phone (a52) from the supported criteria.
Please do help me with the problem and suggest any ideas for how to improve my app responsiveness in the future.

Just take some pictures on a tablet?  It can come from an emulator.  It's not like a tablet is anything special, it's just a slightly bigger device.  The hardware is identical.
